# Why does this case_when command do the command for all cases?

Tags: r, case, multiple-columns, data-wrangling

4 in column 1 represents an answer that means "other". Column 2 represents what that "other" is. I want everything that doesn't have answer 4 in column 1 to have NA in column 2. Using case_when does not give the result I expect.

I have this data

```
col1    col2
1       "a"
4       "c"
4       NA
3       NA
```

I run:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(col2 = case_when(col1 != 4 ~ NA))
```

And expect:

```
col1    col2
1       NA
4       "c"
4       NA
3       NA
```

But I get

```
col1    col2
1       NA
4       NA
4       NA
3       NA
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `case_when` has no case for `col2 == 4`. Therefore NA is returned. According to the docs:

> If no cases match, NA is returned.

To fix that add a default value via `TRUE ~ col2` to your case_when:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1, 4, 4, 3),
  col2 = c("a", "c", NA, NA)
)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(col2 = case_when(
    col1 != 4 ~ NA_character_, 
    TRUE ~ col2))
#>   col1 col2
#> 1    1 <NA>
#> 2    4    c
#> 3    4 <NA>
#> 4    3 <NA>
```

Comment: It definitely works, but I'm not sure why. However a lot of the answers return as empty (not NA).

Comment: (: `TRUE ~ col2` makes sure that there is always a matching case or more precisely a fallback option if no other case matches. The reason why this works is that the condition `TRUE` is, well, always TRUE.

Comment: Yeah I read up on it, it looks like there needs to be an operater for in the case that it's not true. But how come some of the rows display an empty cell and others NA in col2?